# calculate sum of time difference

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
DECLARE @AbandonTime int
SET @AbandonTime += (SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(second,CheckinTime,ServiceStart)) FROM Interaction
WHERE ServiceEnd = '00:00:00.000')
SELECT @AbandonTime
```

and it returns null where when i run only this part.

```
SELECT COUNT(DATEDIFF(second,CheckinTime,ServiceStart)) FROM Interaction
    WHERE ServiceEnd = '00:00:00.000'
```

It returns 1378 records. How to calculate sum of time difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the value, because `NULL` plus any value is still `NULL`:

```
DECLARE @AbandonTime int;
SET @AbandonTime = 0;

SET @AbandonTime += (SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(second, CheckinTime, ServiceStart))
                     FROM Interaction
                     WHERE ServiceEnd = '00:00:00.000'
                    );
SELECT @AbandonTime;
```

Of course, you can simplify this to:

```
DECLARE @AbandonTime int;

SELECT @AbandonTim = SUM(DATEDIFF(second, CheckinTime, ServiceStart))
FROM Interaction
WHERE ServiceEnd = '00:00:00.000';

SELECT @AbandonTime;
```